# What is the best iteration method used in finite element software?

Tags: finite-element-method

Finite element analysis software uses iteration to find displacement vector. There are many methods like multigrid and conjugate gradient methods. Which is the best method to iterate the required vector so that the computation time taken is minimized?

Comment: While some methods are really of strictly pedagogical and/or theoretical importance, there is still no real answer to this questions. Different methods have their merits in different contexts. Multigrid in particular is designed for a very specific purpose: to deal with problems where a fine grid is required to resolve high frequency modes but where low frequency modes converge slowly on such fine grids.

Comment: Perhaps you might be interested in: https://www.netlib.org/templates/templates.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There are different types of iterations used in finite element solvers.

1. Iterations due to nonlinearity. Finite element methods cannot usually directly deal with nonlinear problems and hence the problems are linearized. This leads to iterative methods such as *Newton's method* or *fixed point method*.
2. Iterations for solving in time. The most typical approach is to use a finite difference method in time and finite element method in space. For this approach we need an initial guess and an iteration over time steps. The list of such methods include *explicit Euler*, *implicit Euler*, *Runge-Kutta* and *Crank-Nicholson*.
3. Iterations for solving the resulting linear systems $Ax=b$.

Number 3 is probably the one that you are concerned with in this question. The best method depends on the properties of the matrix $A$: there is no single method which works for every case.

Standard iterative method for symmetric matrices (also in applications other than FEM) is the *conjugate gradient method*. For finite element analysis, this is usually coupled with various *preconditioners* in order to obtain the solution in a smaller amount of steps. A good black box preconditioner is provided by the *incomplete Cholesky factorization*.

For nonsymmetric problems the iterative solvers generally require more iterations to finish. Methods include *GMRES* and *BiCGSTAB*. Preconditioners should be used if possible, but I don't know enough of nonsymmetric preconditioners to comment on this.

*Multigrid methods* are based on the idea of iterating with multiple grids/meshes. The high oscillatory component of the solution can be solved very quickly using a dense mesh and few steps with a simple iterative method such as *Jacobi iteration* or *Gauss-Seidel method*. The low oscillatory component can be solved using coarser grid and possibly even using a direct method (non-iterative solution methods such as Cholesky or LU decomposition). These different methods for different grids/meshes are combined to obtain the solution quickly.

*Algebraic multigrid method* is a black box method that requires no knowledge of the underlying equations. *Geometric multigrid methods* require knowledge of the underlying partial differential equation. They may give you more performance but require more effort to implement.

AFAIK, geometric multigrid method (when applicable) is generally considered to be one of the fastest methods for solving discretized PDE's. However, usually I have seen these applied to very simple PDE's (say, Poisson equation) only.